# Is it possible to make mysqldump skip the inserts for specific table?

Tags: mysql

I'm regularly running `mysqldump` against a Drupal database and man, those cache tables can get huge. Considering that the first thing I do after reloading the data is clear the cache, I'd love it if I could just skip dumping all those rows altogether. I don't want to skip the table creation (with --ignore-tables), I just want to skip all those rows of cached data.

Is it possible to tell `mysqldump` to dump the `CREATE TABLE` statement skip the `INSERT` statements for a specific set of tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `mysqldump` twice.

The [mysql-stripped-dump script](https://github.com/amenk/SelfScripts/blob/master/mysql-stripped-dump) does exactly this.

Answer (score 10):

There is a `--no-data` option that does this, but it affects all tables AFAIK. So, you'll have to run `mysqldump` twice.

```
# Dump all but your_special_tbl
mysqldump --ignore-table=db_name.your_special_tbl db_name > dump.sql

# Dump your_special_tbl without INSERT statements.
mysqldump --no-data db_name your_special_tbl >> dump.sql
```